# Getting value from MathQuill

Tags: javascript

I am using [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/) I would like to get the values of the fraction I got it using Split which wasn't robust !

```
var str="\frac{12}{3}+\frac{2}{3}";
```

How to get the values of a fraction using JavaScript ! I found that I should use regrex ! I am new to javascript regrex ! I want values as

```
var fra1=12;
var fra2=3;
var fra3=2;
var fra4=3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *have* to use regex, and you only need it for this particular string, then the simplest method is to use `.match` and convert to number:

```js
const str = "\frac{12}{3}+\frac{2}{3}";
const frasStrings = str.match(/\d+/g);
const frasNumbers = frasStrings.map(Number);
console.log(frasNumbers);
```

Comment: `\d+` matches any sequence of digits. The `g` flag makes the regex global, so it captures *all* sequences of digits. But the sequences captured (now in `frasStrings`) are still strings, so you need to convert them to numbers, which is done with the `Number` function.